# How to access mysql databases of an old hard drive that is being used as an external disk now?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I've replaced my hard disk with a new SSD. I use the old disk as an external one. 
The old disk has mysql 5.7 and mysql workbench 6.3. I need to access all my databases and copy them to the new disk.

My new disk has mysql 8.0 and workbench 8.0. I tried to copy the data folder from Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Workbench 6.3 CE\ to C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Workbench 8.0 CE\ and restarted mySQL server with no luck.

My old dish had windows 7, now my new disk has windows 10.

Can you please help me?

Comment: It is NEVER a good idea copying databases between major versions. Specially to MySQL8 from previous version as 8 is so different.

Comment: @RiggsFolly Unfortunately I did not keep a mysql dump. Is there a way to restore my databases?

Comment: Boot from old disk temporary. Backup databases. Boot from new disk. Restore databases. Do not forget to check SQL mode compatibility.

Comment: I would remove the MySQL8 service and then install the 5.7 service, amending the directory where it finds data accordingly. Backup you databases. Then switch back to MySQL8 and import the backups

Comment: Boot your old HDD, then get MySQL dumps and import them onto your shiny new SSD.

Comment: @mitkosoft Is there a way to boot without replacing the disks?

Comment: @zinon, if your PC (BIOS) supports boot from external drive, then yes.

Comment: @mitkosoft I tried and unfortunately my drive can't start windows. However, when access the folders as an external hard drive, I can see all the contents of files and folders. Any other idea?

Comment: @zinon, try to install the same MySQL version (5.7) on your new SSD, copy the entire content from the old one and try then to make a dump.

Comment: @mitkosoft Do you refer on the mysql server or also the workbench?

Comment: The server would be enough. You can use any mysql UI or console to prepare the dumps afterward.

Comment: @mitkosoft I did it. I copied /data folder to C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\ and `mysql_config.pl` has `my $ldata   = 'C:/Program Files/MySQL/MySQL Server 5.7/data';`. However, accessing `mysql` I can't see my databases. I also restarted mysql server.